# Google Sheet API - Service account with Domain Wide Delegation - The request is missing a valid API key

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am using the GAPI library v75 on Node.

I am successfully making calls to the Google Classroom API with a service account and domain wide delegation, in order to make changes in the user's context.

I now need to access a Google Sheet so have activated the Sheets API and authorised the required scopes in the admin console. Here is the code:

```
  const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', jwtObject});
        sheets.spreadsheets.get({spreadsheetId : thisSheetId}, function(err, returnValue) {
            if (err)  {
                res.json(err)
            } else {
                res.json(returnValue.data)
            }
        });
```

JWT being generated via:

```
 var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
         client_email,
         null,
         private_key,
         scopes,
         emailToImpersonate
  );

jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
  if (err) {
      console.error('Unable to authenticate with google:', err);

      return
  }

  callback(err, jwtClient)
```

I generated the JWT exactly the same way that I generate for the classroom API and the Admin SDK and they both work fine. But for the sheets API, I receive:

```
"code":403,"errors":[{"message":"The request is missing a valid API key.","domain":"global","reason":"forbidden"}]
```

I do not understand why if I am passing a valid JWT why I need to provide an API key - I did try generating an API key, and then I received a permissions error, which makes sense as the sheet is not public.

Thank you for any help in pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', jwtObject});
```

#### To:

```
const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth: jwtObject});
```

#### Note:

- When I tested `const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', jwtObject});`, I confirmed the same issue with you. So, when I modified your script like the above, I confirmed that the issue was resolved and the values are retrieved from Spreadsheet.

Comment: Ah great, that seems to be it. I found that if I placed the call to the gapi library in a function then it seems happy without having the "auth" item directly specified. But much clearer like this. Thanks!

Comment: @John Gerhardt Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying and current situation, I cannot understand whether your issue was resolved. Can I ask you whether my answer was useful for resolving your issue?

Comment: Yep this did fix it, Thanks!